# NLH Probablility of Drawing a hand

Tags: nlhe, probability

When dealt 5 cards from a deck the probabilities of seeing a str8 flush, 4 of kind, full house, flush, str8, 3 of kind, two pair, pair, or high card are well known and easily computed: str8 flush .0015%, 4 of kind .024%, full house .14%, ... and so on ...

Do these probabilities hold true in real holdem?

That is, if I were sitting at a table dealt 1,000,000 hands and sat through all betting rounds right to the river, then I should expect my best 5 card holdem hand out of the 7 cards available to me would be a str8 flush .0015%, 4 of kind .024%, full house .14%, ... and so on ...

Is this true?

Comment: No, the probabilities are different. But it should be easy to find a 5-out-of-7 table.

Comment: I asked a similar question in the math forums. And I was pointed to the table here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability#7-card_poker_hands